# "At what age" vs. "from what age"

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning and usage between *at what age* and *from what age*? For example:

> **At**/**From** what age are you allowed to drive a car in your country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*At the age of...* refers to something happening during a particular year of a person's life, often a single occurrence. "I left school at the age of sixteen."

Obviously you can drive a car at any age once you have passed your test, but there is a minimum age for taking the driving test. So you need *From what age...?* here.

Comment: Great answer. Another set of examples would be, “At what age was he married? From what age to what age did he remain married? By what age was he divorced?”